# Custom style is not loaded for "Visitors" in custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, custom-masterpage

In custom master page,the customized styles are loaded  completely for members under visitors group only if we publish all the files.But in Seatle,there is no need for us to publish any files.The styles are properly loaded.What method have they implemented in Seattle?